# How to avoid music volume sudden increase by long pressing of volume button

Tags: android, button, background, volume

I want to design an app to avoid this accidental long press on the volume button to avoid music volume's sudden increase.

In the activity, I can manage to do that by simply override the onKeyDown method.

However, in the background, there is no way to monitor the hardware key press (At least what I have found). I have tried several ways:

1. Use ContentObserver to monitor the volume change at background, then adjust the music volume back to original. It works, however, the system's music volume will always be increased first then adjusted back.
   I know several other existing app can already do this, but I don't want to do this. The small gap is very annoying if you keep pressing the volume button.
2. I tried to fire the main activity in the content observer (since I can override the volume key in the activity), however, it is still not simultaneous. It is even worse. Because it takes a longer time to start the activity.

So is there any other suggestion that I can overcome this problem? If I can root  my phone, is it possible to monitor the key press at background?

Also, if there is no way to override the volume button at background, is there any way to set the max volume for the stream_music?

Appreciated!